# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. While attempting to import TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the following error while attempting to import TensorFlow. I tried rolling back to C++ Redist. 2015 (from 2017) and still not working. Win10, Python 3.5(64)

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname)
>   File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
>   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "",
>   line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File "",
>   line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 666, in
>   _load_unlocked File "", line 577, in module_from_spec File "", line 914, in create_module File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 21, in
>   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper return
>   importlib.import_module('pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\importlib_init.py", line 126, in import_module return
>   _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py", line 24, in from
>   tensorflow.python import * File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_init_.py", line 51,
>   in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 52, in raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname)
>   File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
>   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "",
>   line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File "",
>   line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 666, in
>   _load_unlocked File "", line 577, in module_from_spec File "", line 914, in create_module File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 21, in
>   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper return
>   importlib.import_module('pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File
>   "C:\Python35\lib\importlib_init.py", line 126, in import_module return
>   _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Installed the non-GPU version and it works. Any ideas how to get the GPU version woking, given the above errors?

Comment: If it the non-GPU version works, but the GPU version doesn't, this suggests a problem with the CUDA installation. Can you ensure that the DLLs for both CUDA 8.0 and cuDNN 5.1 are in directories in your `%PATH%` environment variable?

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use 6.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Working setup in Windows 10 and GTX960M:

- Install python 3.5.x
- Microsoft visual studio 2015 community edition.
- Download and install CUDA toolkit 8.0
- Download CuDNN v5.1.
- Set CUDA_HOME (\CUDA) and %CUDA_HOME%\bin in PATH.
- Extract the cuDNN files to a folder and add that location(the folder where bin,lib, include folders are) also to PATH make sure that cuDNN DLLs are properly set in %PATH%.
- Copy the respective files from cuDNN to folders in cuda installation directory(This solved my issues):
  copy cudnn64_5.dll to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin.
  copy cudnn.h to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include.
  copy cudnn.lib to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64.
- Make sure that I have MSVCP140.dll in C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64. If not download it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587 and install it.

I strongly think these versioning is a bit important in this case.
I tried using cuDNN 6.0 which failed. but 5.1 worked.

Comment: This definitely helps!

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 1.3 then you want to use CuDNN 6.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7705