# Can´t import tensorflow into project

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I want to use tensorflow in a python project.

This is the only code in my project.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I´ve got this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alexa/PycharmProjects/tensorFlow/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf 
  File "C:\Users\Alexa\PycharmProjects\tensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Alexa\PycharmProjects\tensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Alexa\PycharmProjects\tensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Alexa\PycharmProjects\tensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I use PyCharm and Python 3.6 in a Virtualenv in PyCharm. 
How can I fix this and run tensorflow?

Comment: It seems that, as the error message says, the loading of the DLL failed. `tensorflow` is largely built in C/C++ and thus has C-Extensions (which are compiled to DLL files on windows). If python can't load these DLLs (either because they are errored or don't exist), tensorflow won't work. Reinstalling tensorflow might solve the problem.

Comment: This here is the same question, though the answer doesn't seem super clear. See if it can help you in any way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727917

Comment: So I tried it and it dosen´t work. In Visual Studio 17 I´ve got the same error. 
DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

Comment: You have your tensorflow installed in a virtual environment, if I'm seeing that correctly. Have you tried installing tensorflow to the default package site (no virual environment)? The problem might come from virtualenv losing the DLLs at some point in the installation process.

Comment: have tried this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949

Comment: Did you use Anaconda as a base interpreter for creating a venv?